# Replay Debugger Filters

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, debug-logs, apex-debugger, apex-replay-debugger

Does anyone knows if we are able to filter Replay Debugger Logs?

I mean, lets say we have a collection of data, which will be iterated 1000 times. Let's say we are interested to see what data are being processed at iteration number 760, but i don't want click on 'play' button 760 times.

Let's say I know some value that will be there for sure at iteration number 760, for example Name of the record (for this purpose it will be 'Iteration Name 760').

My question is, is it posible to stop Replay Debugger at iteration where Name = 'Iteration Name 760' so I can see what's the information of that record? (instead of clicking 760 times play button, and checking constantly if that record is the one I need to focus in)

Many Thanks in advance!

[EDIT]
I have tried on WATCH/INSPECTOR, but somehow I cannot assign 'Expresion -> Value' as when you set it, Key/Value pair, has same value (for APEX) I've seen that for other languages you are able to change key/value pair.

[image: VisualStudioCode]

Some Idea? this would be great while debuggin big ammount of data, so you don't have to manually pressing F10 or Play button hundred times in order to find desired record.

Thanks!